# number of subsets of a set which contains sets as individual elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider set S{{},{a},{b,c},{c},d} number of subsets of this set would be ?
And how to deal with these kinds of sets within sets
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean that you have a set called $a$ that contains $\{a\}$ as an element? That situation is not allowed by standard set theory.

Comment: Yes.{a} is an individual element that set

Comment: This question is very unclear, please edit it so that people know exactly what you are asking

Comment: @viru: Then you must be working in a non-standard set theory. Usual set theory (ZFC with the Axiom of Regularity) does not allow infinitely descending chains such as $$ \cdots \in a \in \{a\}\in a \in \{a\} \in a $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a set of five elements*, and it can be treated as such. Think about it the same way you would $\lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \rbrace$. It has $2^5$ subsets, which hopefully you can list. The sets in the above set are just substitutes for those numbers. I won't list them all, but here are some examples of subsets of this set:

$$\lbrace \lbrace \rbrace, d \rbrace, \lbrace \lbrace a \rbrace \rbrace, \lbrace \lbrace b, c \rbrace, \lbrace c \rbrace, \lbrace \rbrace \rbrace$$

*It is five elements unless $a = c$, $d = \lbrace \rbrace$, $d = \lbrace a \rbrace$, $d = \lbrace b, c \rbrace$, or $d = \lbrace c \rbrace$. Basically, it's a five element set provided that none of the elements are sneaky repeats of each other!